# Couldn't Spring Webflux or Non blocking pattern be bad for scaling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I get that with threads being nonblocking, we don't need to have Thread sprawl depending on N concurrent requests, but rather we put our tasks in a single event loop in our reactive web programming pattern.

Yes, that can help, but since the event loop is a queue, what if the first task to be processed blocks forever? Then the event loop will never progress and thus end of responses and processing other than queueing more tasks. Yes, timeouts are probably possible, but I can't wrap my head around how the event loop can be a good solution.

Say you have 3 tasks that take 3 seconds to wait for IO and run each executions and they got submitted to the event queue. Then they will still take 9 seconds to be able to be processed and also to execute once IO resolved. In the case of making threads that block, this would have resolved in 3 seconds since they run concurrently.

Where I can see a benefit is if the event loop is not really a queue and upon signal that a task is ready to be processed, it dispatches that task to be processed. In that case though, this would mean that order of task execution is not maintained and also each task has to still be running a thread in order to be able to tell when IO is resolved.

Maybe I am not understanding the event loop and thread handling correctly. Can someone correct me please because it seems like this Reactor pattern seems to make things possibly worse.

Lastly, upon X requests in Spring Reactor, does only 1 thread get created to run handlers instead of the traditional X threads? In that case, if someone accidently wrote blocking code, doesnt that mean each subsequent requests get queued?

Comment: Is your question about Spring Reactor or event loops?

Comment: Both since spring reactor uses event loops

Comment: Not really. Where did you get that information?

Comment: "WebFlux stack delivers entirely non-blocking I/O within an event loop model." From https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-5-FAQ

Comment: I see, but Webflux is not Reactor.

Comment: Iirc, it was originally spring reactor web and later renamed to spring webflux

Comment: Reactor is a standalone project that implements reactive streams. Webflux (or whatever it was called before) is a web framework, or the web part of the Spring framework, whatever you prefer. Webflux uses Reactor. Contrary to the classical Servlet model it's not using one thread per request. How many it uses is another question. And how many threads are used by the streams you create is completely independent from Webflux. Even if Webflux had one thread accepting requests (the "event loop"), the handlers would still run on an arbitrary number of threads.

Comment: Yes, but I will get back to you once I do some more research on thr event loop, since i think you might be mixing up the server request accepting loop with the event loop. Maybe its different in the reactive world, so I will need to get back to you on that

Comment: Accepting may not be the right word, let's use dispatching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use the event loop for long running tasks. This is considered an anti-pattern. Usually it is merely used for quickly picking up imminent events, but not actually doing the work associated with these events if the work would block the event loop noticeably. You would want to use a separate thread pool for executing long running tasks. So the event loop would usually only *initiate* work using asynchronous and hence non-blocking structures (or actually doing the work only if it can be done very quickly) and pass the heavier and possibly blocking tasks to a separate thread pool (for CPU intensive computations) or to the operating system (such as data buffers to be sent over the network).

Also, don't be fooled by the fact that only one thread is dealing with the events, it is very fast and is usually enough for even demanding applications. Platforms like NodeJS or frameworks like Netty (used in Akka, Play framework, Apache Cassandra, etc.) are using an event loop at their heart with great success. One should just be aware of the fact, that performing blocking operations inside the event loop is generally a bad idea.

Please have a look at some of these posts for more information:

- [The reactor pattern and non blocking IO](https://www.celum.com/de/blog/technologie/the-reactor-pattern-and-non-blocking-io)
- [Unix Network Programming](http://www.masterraghu.com/subjects/np/introduction/unix_network_programming_v1.3/ch06lev1sec2.html)
- [Kotlin Webflux](https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/kotlin-webflux/)
- Slightly off topic but still a very prominent example: [Don't Block the Event Loop (NodeJS)](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/)

Comment: Hello xSRNG, upvoted for the helpful links and confirmation of anti-pattern. However, I will accept this as soon as you can explain "Event loops are only strong if tasks do not block the event loop.... good fit when dealing with asynchronous I/O, which is at the core of Spring Reactor."

In my question, I've conveyed that, when dealing with asynchronous I/O, in order to hear back that the I/O has completed, a separate thread needs to be listening for it. But after reading your link, it seems with NIO, you can use channels instead which is handled at a lower level(no threads).Is that correct?

Comment: And I say this, because in Java NIO, a Selector running on a single thread can handle multiple Channels

Comment: I tried to add a few explanations to the text above until I realized I could write pages of text more about this topic. Instead, I added two more links "Unix Network Programming" which is pretty much the foundation for all of the frameworks we were talking about (Java NIO, Netty, Webflux, etc.) and "Kotlin Webflux" which I think could be a good text to read. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for the effort! If you ever decide to write one just know id read all of it thanks again!